# Unlimited input in JAVA

Tags: java

I wrote a program to input two arrays of 10 elements each, merge them into another array, remove the duplicate elements. While taking input, the input process does not end at 10 elements for arr2 it goes on non-stop.

```
import java.util.*;
class ReDep
{ 
 public static void main()
 {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the values of arr1");
    int arr1[]=new int[10];
    int arr2[]=new int[10];
    int arr3[]=new int[20];
    int i,j,k,l,g,h,n,c,d,size,f;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arr1[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Enter the values of arr2" );
    for(f=0;f<10;f++)
    {

        arr2[f]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        arr3[j]=arr1[j];
        arr3[j+10]=arr3[j];
    }
    for(k=0;k<19;k++)
    {
        for(l=0;l<=19-(k+1);l++)
        {
            if(arr3[l]>=arr3[l+1])
            {
                c=arr3[l];
                arr3[l]=arr3[l+1];
                arr3[l+1]=c;
            }
        }}
    size=19;
    for(g=0;g<size;g++)
    {
        if(arr3[g]==arr3[g+1])
        {
            n=g+1;
            while(n<=size)
            {
                arr3[n]=arr3[n+1];
            }
            size--;
        }
    }
    for(d=0;d<20;d++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr3[d]);
    }
 }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: In the future, please use a debugger first before posting a question that is basically little more than a typo or careless error. Or if you don't yet know how to use a debugger, then sprinkle the code with println statements, but again first do some debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an infinite while you haven't increment n or decrement size :

```
while(n<=size)
{
    arr3[n]=arr3[n+1];
}
```

u have to increment it :)

```
while(n<=size)
{
    arr3[n]=arr3[n+1];
    n++; // or size--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    arr3[j]=arr1[j];
    //change arr3[j] to arr2[j]
    arr3[j+10]=arr2[j];
}
```

And fix your main method's signature.

Comment: Why should i change arr3[j] to arr2[j]?

Comment: Because you just copy values inside arr3 array itself without it.

Comment: I did not get your point. I am merging the elements of arr1 and arr2 into arr3.

Comment: Check carefully again the difference between `arr3[j+10]=arr3[j];` and `arr3[j+10]=arr3[j];` expressions, the first one assings the value itself.

Comment: @MrAP try my answer , i think it's because of an infinite loop